# unable to get all grade(manytomanyfiled) in django detailview

Tags: django, tags, django-queryset, detailview

i want to get subject according to grade. (E.g English include in grade 5th,6th etc)i have tried many thing but unable to get manytomany filed view in detailview

i have tried queryset tag on template and queryset function in detailview

model.py

```py
class grade(models.Model):
    Grade = models.CharField(null = True,max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField( default='',editable=False,max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.Grade)
        super(grade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('grade-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % (self.Grade)

class subjects(models.Model):
    Book = models.CharField(null = True,max_length=100)
    Grade = models.ManyToManyField('grade')
    slug = models.SlugField( default='',editable=False,max_length=100)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.Book)
        super(subjects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('subjects-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % (self.Book)
```

view.py

```py
class subjectsdetailview(DetailView):
    model = subjects
    template_name = 'myapp/subjects_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        mysub = subjects.objects.order_by('Book')
        return mysub
```

my html tag code

```html
<h3>Detail</h3>
  <ul><h5>Subject:  <font color="blue">{{subjects.Book}}</font></h5> </ul>
  <ul><h5>Grade:  <font color="blue">{{subjects.Grade.all}}</font></h5> </ul>
  <a href="{% url 'subjects-delete' subjects.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Delete</a>
  <a href="{% url 'subjects-update' subjects.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Edit</a>
```

result is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVeZJ.jpg)

Comment: Have you actually added any `Grade` to `subjects`?

Comment: Yes 1 have 5 entries in grade